# Spring: How to get the "ACTUAL" / "CURRENT" locale like it works for messages?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, locale, gettext

I am a bit puzzled, as I have a working system but I cannot get the actual/current locale.

The working system is about this:

For example from: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Some messages.properties file,

A servlet-context.xml file with:

```
  <!-- Additional i18n -->
  <bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="translationService" class="inbiz.webapp.service.TranslationService">
  </bean>
  <alias name="translationService" alias="t" />

  <mvc:interceptors>
    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" 
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
      <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
    </bean>
  </mvc:interceptors>
  <!-- END: Additional i18n -->
```

For the TranslationService (even if not directly related to the question check also: [java spring mvc @service method: nullpointerexception | newbie and translation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657397/java-spring-mvc-service-method-nullpointerexception-newbie-and-translation))

This apparently makes already everything working within the like of the first link. So I can do:

```
<a href="" th:text="#{help}">Help</a>
```

This is thymeleaf (http://www.thymeleaf.org/) but basically the same as JSP or JSF .. The messages get loaded with the correct locale.

But for my TranslationService I need to get the locale just like the messages bundle does.

Following: https://templth.wordpress.com/2010/07/21/configuring-locale-switching-with-spring-mvc-3/, I set up this filter:

```
package inbiz.webapp.filters;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;

import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils;

import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

public class LocaleConfigurerFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private LocaleResolver localeResolver;


    protected void initFilterBean() throws ServletException {

    Locale locale;

        WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
        Map resolvers = wac.getBeansOfType(LocaleResolver.class);
        if (resolvers.size()==1) {
            localeResolver = (LocaleResolver) resolvers.values().iterator().next();
        }

    locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE LCH - INIT: "+locale);

    }


    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {

    Locale locale;

    WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());

        Map resolvers = wac.getBeansOfType(LocaleResolver.class);
        if (resolvers.size()==1) {
            localeResolver = (LocaleResolver) resolvers.values().iterator().next();
        }
        if (localeResolver!=null) {
            locale = localeResolver.resolveLocale(req);
        System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE LRS: "+locale);
            LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(locale);
        }

    locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
    System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE LCH: "+locale);
    locale = RequestContextUtils.getLocale((HttpServletRequest) req);
    System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE RCU: "+locale);
    LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(locale);

    chain.doFilter(req, res);

    }

}
```

The filter gets called, but the output is just:

```
DEBUG FILTER LOCALE LCH - INIT: en_US
DEBUG FILTER LOCALE LCH: en_US
DEBUG FILTER LOCALE RCU: en_US
DEBUG FILTER LOCALE LCH: en_US
DEBUG FILTER LOCALE RCU: en_US
DEBUG FILTER LOCALE LCH: en_US
DEBUG FILTER LOCALE RCU: en_US
```

Even if any page is called with something like: ?lang=it_IT

(which indeed works for the messages.properties)

I am sorry it might be too many information... but as I say I am a bit lost in understanding who keeps the actual locale. Also as the next step will be to set the locale from the user profile, but I need a controlled default if the user is not logged in.

So the final question: How do I get the locale?

I think, I miss some fundamental points ... and the solution is just one line. But at present I finished my "web" resources.. ;) Maybe a wrong search..

On the other side I give a bit of information, so that it might help
other people trying to implement a "gnu gettext" version.

Comment: Indeed I would like to move out from a filter. As, once the language is set, all the pages should be given in that language. But I would still use the messages.properties mechanism. This is why it might be important to know who, how and when a locale is stored within spring.

Comment: Sorry, extra comment: It works. I can currently use xgettext to extract PO/POT lines from java and even to extract HTML template lines like gettext:_="string" within thymeleaf dialect. As soon as I get it running I will blog about.

Answer (score 7):

1. First of all, let's consider how the `LocaleResolver` is registered in a Spring context (pay attentiona, that default locale is set):

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableWebMvc
   @ComponentScan(value = "com.locales.package")
   public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

       @Bean(name = "localeResolver")
       public LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver(){
           CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
           localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
           return localeResolver;
       }

   ...
   // Other beans        
   ...

   }
   ```
2. At last in our controller (or another place) we can get current locale:

   ```
   @Autowired
   private LocaleResolver localeResolver;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView resolveLocale(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) {
       Locale locale = localeResolver.resolveLocale(request);

       ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
       modelAndView.setViewName("index");
       modelAndView.addObject("currentLocale", locale.getDisplayLanguage());

       return modelAndView;
   }
   ```
3. Then we can display the result at `JSP` (index.jsp):

   ```
   <h1>Current locale = ${currentLocale}</h1>
   ```

Answer (score 3):

try the following code which i use in my JSP to display the locale:

```
${pageContext.response.locale}
```

Answer (score 0):

I post it as an answer:

In my bean id="localeResolver" I define SessionLocaleResolver
as "resolver".

So now a new code like this:

```
protected void initFilterBean() throws ServletException {

try {
    sessionLocaleResolver = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    //System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE SLR - INIT: Got SLR ");
} catch (Exception e) {
    //System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE SLR - INIT: CANNOT START ");
    logger.error("Could not intialize SessionLocaleResolver.");
}

}


@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
throws IOException, ServletException {

Locale newLocale;
    if (sessionLocaleResolver!=null) {
    newLocale = sessionLocaleResolver.resolveLocale(req);
    if (newLocale!=null){
    System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE OLD: "+locale);
    System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE NEW: "+newLocale);
    if (locale != newLocale){
        System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE CALL: "+locale);
        if (locale != null){
        //t.updateLocale(newLocale);
        }
    }
    locale = newLocale;
    //System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE SLR: "+locale);
    logger.debug("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE: In filter session: Locale {}.", locale);
    LocaleContextHolder.setLocale(locale);
    } else {
    //System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE SLR - FILTER: NO RESOLVER");
    logger.error("In session: Could not resolve locale SessionLocaleResolver.");
    }
} else {
    //System.out.println("DEBUG FILTER LOCALE SLR - FILTER: WAS NULL");
    logger.error("In session: Could not get SessionLocaleResolver.");
}

chain.doFilter(req, res);

}
```

I can actually use the:

sessionLocaleResolver.resolveLocale(req);

which resolves to the correct locale.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your Spring Boot i18n config working for messages you can simply get current locale, using Thymeleaf, this way:

```
<input th:value="${#locale.language}"/>
```

Value got like: "en".

Of course you may use another valid tag or th: combination ;)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Without adding any model.attribute from controllers.